# Why is the displacement texture weaker on certain parts of the object?

Tags: materials, shaders, displacement, bump

I'm trying to make some rock textures but the displacement isn't showing across the entire object. This has always been an issue but it hasn't bothered me that much up until now

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Displacement Node (Vector > Displacement) between the Noise Texture and the displacement connection of the Material Output:

[image: Displace]